# How can I calculate the number of geodesics (shortest paths) going through a vertex or an edge in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, sna

The `betweeness` function in **igraph** of **R** defines the edge betweeness as the the number of geodesics (shortest paths) going through.

However, the `edge_betweenness_centrality` in **networkx** of **python** defines it in a [traditional way](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality.html), which seems to require a heavier computational load.

My question is, how can I calculate that of R under networkx to save time?

---

For example, I created a circular graph containing 2000 nodes and 4000 edges both in R and python. The time spent for computation is presented as follow.

R

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)

G <- play_smallworld(n_dim = 1, dim_size = 2000,
                     order = 2,
                     p_rewire = 0)

start <- Sys.time()
edge_betweenness(G)
end <- Sys.time()

print(end - start)
Time difference of 0.1190271 secs
```

Python

```py
import networkx as nx
import time

G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n = 2000,
    k = 4,
    p = 0)

start = time.time()
nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G)
end = time.time()

print('Runing time: %s Seconds' %(end-start))
Runing time: 12.19289755821228 Seconds
```

Comment: How would it be less of a computational workload? If I understand correctly, one definition of bc is # of shortest paths through e, the other one is % of shortest paths through e. In both cases, you compute all shortest paths so 0(V3) (possibly slightly less using priority queue and dijkstra if your network isn't too dense).

Comment: @gchapuis, I reedit my question. Your answer must be right but I cannot figure out why networkx spent a lot more time. Maybe I made something wrong.

Comment: That's a big difference indeed! Are you sure both networks are identical?

Comment: Both libraries seem to implement Brandes' algorithm (http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/publications/b-fabc-01.pdf). Networkx seems to be pure Python while R's Igraph is C. That explains at least part of the running time difference but most likely not all of it. There is however an Igraph package for Python but I'm guessing you'd like to stick with networkx, right?

Comment: @gchapuis, Thanks! I am pretty sure these two networks are identical. And I will try igraph for python.